# What are the V speeds for a Piper Super Cub 180HP with an upgrade to 61 gallons fuel capacity?

Tags: v-speeds

I fly a Piper Super Cub 180HP with upgraded 61 gallons, 30.5 gallons usable a side. The POH and everywhere I look online I find POHs for Cubs with 150hp and 36 gallons TOTAL. I was wondering if anyone knew where to find the speeds for this upgraded Super Cub?

Comment: Isn't this part of the STC documentation when the mod was performed? I believe it's required to be an addendum to the POH...

Comment: There should be an addendum to the POH, however, the other flight characteristics didn't change, so you could calculate them yourself using a current weighing report.

Comment: Before you even get that far, does the STC for the bigger engine and extra fuel include a gross wt increase? (usually this is not the case because it would require the STC maker to do a ton of testing)  If there is no GW increase, you will use the regular numbers. Or, perhaps this airplane is a Wag Aero homebuilt Super Cub?  If that's the case, the builder should have created a POH and if not you are on your own.